# Defining constants with $GLOBALS

Tags: php, variables, global

I want to use a global variable setup where they are all declared, initialized and use friendly syntax in PHP so I came up with this idea:

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

$GLOBALS['debugger'] = 1;                   // set $GLOBALS['debugger'] to 1 
DEFINE('DEBUGGER','$GLOBALS["debugger"]');  // friendly access to it globally

echo "1:" . DEBUGGER . ":<br>";
echo "2:" . ${DEBUGGER}. ":<br>";
echo "3:" . $GLOBALS['debugger'] . ":<br>";
if (DEBUGGER==1) {echo "DEBUG SET";}
?>
```

generates the following:

> 1:$GLOBALS["debugger"]:
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: $GLOBALS["debugger"] in /home/tra50118/public_html/php/test.php on line 8
>
> 2::
>
> 3:1:

How can there be an error with 2: when clearly `$GLOBALS["debugger"]` IS defined? And then not generate a similar notice with the test at line 10?

I think what I am trying to do is to force PHP to interpret a string (`$GLOBALS["debugger"]`) as a variable at run time i.e. a constant variable variable

Comment: **Suggestion:** Stop. Don't do it. Forget about globals. Seriously.

Comment: You're not supposed to use globals because globals are not nice.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** I agree with the comments, globals are generally a bad idea.

That said, there's a few questions here that are worth answering, and the concept of indirection is useful, so here goes.

`${'$GLOBALS["debugger"]'}` is undefined. You don't include the leading `'$'` when using indirection. So, the correct version would be `define('DEBUGGER', 'GLOBALS["debugger"]')`.

**But**, this doesn't work either. You can only access one level down via indirection. So you can access the array `$GLOBALS`, but you can't access keys in that array. Hence, you might use :

```
define('DEBUGGER', 'debugger');
${DEBUGGER};
```

*This isn't useful, practically.* You may as well just use `$debugger` directly, as it's been defined as a global and will be available everywhere. You may need to define `global $debugger;` at the start of functions however.

The reason your if statement is not causing notices is because you defined `DEBUGGER` to be a string. Since you aren't trying to use indirection in that line at all, it ends up reading as:

```
if ("$GLOBALS['debugger']"==1) {echo "DEBUG SET";}
```

This is clearly never true, though it is entirely valid PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have your constants crossed a bit.

`DEFINE('DEBUGGER','$GLOBALS["debugger"]');` sets the constant `DEBUGGER` to the *string* `$GLOBALS["debugger"]`.
Note that this is neither the value nor the reference, just a string.

Which causes these results:

1:  Output the string `$GLOBALS["debugger"]`
2:  Output the value of the variable named `$GLOBALS["debugger"]`.  Note that this is the variable named "`$GLOBALS["debugger"]`", not the value of the key "debugger" in the array `$GLOBALS`.  Thus a warning occurs, since that variable is undefined.
3:  Output the actual value of `$GLOBALS["debugger"]`

Hopefully that all makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use "variable variables" with any of the superglobal arrays, of which $GLOBALS is one, if you intend to do so inside an array or method.  To get the behavior you would have to use $$, but this will not work as I mentioned.

Constants in php are already global, so I don't know what this would buy you from your example, or what you are going for.

Your last comparison "works" because you are setting the constant to a string, and it is possible with PHP's typecasting to compare a string to an integer.  Of course it evaluates to false, which might be surprising to you, since you expected it to actually work.

Comment: Actually, I don't know about the other superglobals, but when I was running some tests for my own answer, the following *did* work: `$foo = 'GLOBALS'; var_dump(${$foo});`. You just can't index into the array, so it's somewhat useless.

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, that will work, but not inside a function or method.  That's such a severe limitation I pretty much discount its use, but I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to all who answered. I think I get it now, I am new to PHP having come form a C++ background and was treating the define like the C++ `#define` and assuming it just did a string replace in the precompile/run phase.

In precis, I just wanted to use something like

```
DEBUGGER = 1;
```

instead of

```
$GLOBALS['debugger'] = 1;
```

for a whole lot of legitimate reasons; not the least of which is preventing simple typos stuffing you up. Alas, it appears this is not doable in PHP.
Thanks for the help, appreciated.

Comment: Constants are already global in php. You just need to use DEFINE('DEBUGGER', 1);